# Laravel-Many-to-Many Self Referencing Table - Help To find Better Solution

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables, `item` and `item_to_item`.

I have set up model relationship:

```
public function items()
{
 return $this->belongsToMany('Item', 'item_to_item', 'item_id', 'to_item_id');
}
```

Now I need reverse relationship and one solution is to set up second relation:

```
public function item()
    {
     return $this->belongsToMany('Item', 'item_to_item', 'to_item_id', 'item_id');
    }
```

but it is not good solution,This would require calling separately and it will be hard for a list of items,i think

are there any other ways?

Comment: Would you describe, by editing the question text, what is not good about the solution you have? How would another solution improve on it?

Comment: What do you mean by "This would require calling separately and it will be hard for a list of items"?